# Coffeescript how to compile with sourcemap?

Tags: node.js, coffeescript

Here's how I compile:

```
str = CoffeeScript.compile(fs.readFileSync(file, "ascii"))
```

How do I get sourcemaps to work with this.

Comment: Do you just want to generate the sourceMap when compiling, or are you interested in using them after compiling?  The `Error.prepareStackTrace` function in `coffee-script.coffee` is main example I've seen of using the sourceMap (though it does not use the `v3` form).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`CoffeeScript.compile` takes an object as the second argument which has valid values as seen on the [CoffeeScript website](http://coffeescript.org/) under 'Usage'

For your case, you want to use:

```
str = CoffeeScript.compile(fs.readFileSync(file, "ascii"), { map: true });
```

Comment: Do you know where the documentation is on this?

Comment: Maybe in the link I posted in my answer?

Comment: It only talks about the cli and not the js api?

Comment: Well the JS API is pretty much the same thing. Just read the [source](http://coffeescript.org/documentation/docs/coffee-script.html)